# Finite Field Powers

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Suppose we have an element $a \in \mathrm{GF}(p)$ where $p$ is Prime. Is it true, that we always have $a^p = a \mod p$? If so, how would one go about proving this for all $p$?

Comment: Do you already know Fermat's little theorem or Lagrange's theorem for groups?   Please give further context. This will end up being a duplicate question in any case.

Comment: I didn't until now, but I guess Fermats little theorem comes in handy

Comment: Yes it is equivalent to Fermat's little theorem (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4445812/242) for how to show equivalent the two common forms of little Fermat).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More generally in any finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$ (here $q=p^f$ with $p$ prime) one has $
a^q=a\quad\text{for all $a\in\mathbb{F}_q$.}
$
Indeed the multiplicative group $\mathbb{F}_q$ has $q-1$ elements so that if $a\neq0$ a straightforward application of Lagrange's theorem for finite groups gives $a^{q-1}=1$ from which the claim follows at once.

Finally, $0^q=0$ is trivial.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs/PSQs cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).